# ERROR: could not open file ""C:\Users\Zadane\Downloads\Popdata.csv" for reading: No such file or directory

Tags: csv, psql

1. I am login to a database su -postgres
2. psql
3. \c postgres  # connected to database
4. Successfully Created table population

I have a CSV file and I have successfully created table, when I am trying to use the copy command

```
COPY population(year,age,ethnic,sex,area,count)
FROM 'C:\Users\Zadane\Downloads\Popdata.csv'  #( note my CSV file is in my download folders )
DELIMITER ‘,’
CSV HEADER**;
```

I get and error,

> CSV HEADER;ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pwd"
> LINE 1: pwd

When, I remove the Delimiter from the command, I get an error

> ERROR:  could not open file "C:\Users\Zadane\Downloads\Popdata.csv"
> for reading: No such file or directory**

```
\! pwd -shows displays the name:- /home/postgres
```

`SHOW data_directory` shows path:- `/usr/local/postgresql/pgsql/data.`

Can you let me know how to resolve the issue.or how to move .csv file to the `/usr/local/postgres` path,  Or if there is any manually command where i can enter 70 to 80k records in a table.

Comment: `/home/postgres` and `C:\Users\Zadane\Downloads\Popdata.csv` don't match, the former is a Unix(Linux) home directory and the latter is a Windows file path. I am not seeing how that is going to work period.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion @AdrianKlaver, what changes  should i do, how the CSV file can be executed? How the .csv file can be copied to /usr/local/postgresql/pgsql/data

Comment: You need to move the file from the Windows machine to the Linux(I presume) one. You have not provided enough information to say anymore.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, I have launched and Ec2 instance Amazon linux and have attached 4 ebs volumes to it.  2) I connected my instance in gitbash and login to server. 3) I have installed PostgresSQL v 8.4.18 source code installation in my machine by the steps shown in this link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-short.html. 4) My task is to create table with a 70k to 90k records and see which ebs volume it store the data out of 4 ebs volumes.  6) so m trying to create a sample entry inside the database but unable get a code, that is why m trying to download sample csv file and connect it

Comment: 1) Add the information to your question not as a comment 2) Postgres 8.4 is ~8 years past EOL, so why are you using it?

Comment: Just because you attach an EBS volume to an EC2 instance does not mean you can read it. You are using two different file systems so you can't just expect to grab a file from one into another.

Comment: I have got a task to perform and only test it on v 8.4.18 that is why i am using it.

Comment: Any suggestion on how can I create a table with  70-80k records or import a sample csv file?